# How to passing value to an Ext.Net usercontrol and then load it?

Tags: asp.net, ext.net, dynamic-usercontrols

.Net Framework v4.5
Ext.Net v2.2
I use UserControlLoader and works fine, but I need passing properties to my UserControl and then render it.
my usercontrol markup

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditPost.ascx.cs" Inherits="SepanoCMS.Views.EditPost" %>

<ext:Panel RTL="true" ID="pnlEditPost" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Padding="5" Layout="FormLayout" AutoWidth="true"
AutoHeight="true" AnchorHorizontal="100%" Border="false">
<Items>
    <ext:TextField ID="txtTitle" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AnchorHorizontal="100%" />
    <ext:HtmlEditor ID="HtmlEditor1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" MinHeight="150" MaxHeight="600" AnchorHorizontal="100%" />
</Items>
</ext:Panel>
```

I want the value for filling *txtTitle* and *HtmlEditor1* in Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

Create two public property using get set method in user control. pass the value in the property in page load of page where u added the control. then assign that value in control inuser control page load.